# Feature scaling for polynomial regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

Do we have to scale the polynomial features when creating a polynomial regression?

This question is already answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134877/normalization-effect-on-polynomial-regression) and the answer is no. But when creating a model with scikit learn, I do observe a huge difference.

And I also found [this article about the Importance of Feature Scaling in Data Modeling](https://www.robertoreif.com/blog/2017/12/16/importance-of-feature-scaling-in-data-modeling-part-1-h8nla). And the example of polynomial features prove that the scaling does have an impact.

What did I miss ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because of numerical issues; polynomials are prone to ill-conditioning: I have experienced (outside of machine learning) such problems with not-so-complex polynomial models, and the first solution was scaling the values of the features.
Symbolically the result is the same, but numerically can be much different, in some instances